# where is the sqlite's source in android source

Tags: android, sqlite, android-ndk, android-sqlite

all.

I'd like to study the sqlite in android.

Right now,i have the whole source project of android and aready find the lib folder of sqlite in the /external/sqlite.

But,as i know sqlite is runned with its own lib and backhend,pager.Anyway,i can not find out all the source files of sqlite,like pager.c,in the android source project.

Any one can give me a hand?thx

Answer (score 0):

The file `sqlite3.c` is a combination of all the other source files.